# Can I modify Model Metadata inside an action filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to implement a requirement that will allow me to change the state of an html control based on the users role or other business logic. For example some users should not be able to edit a certain model property or in some cases I do not even want the control to render to the html DOM.

Within the HTML helpers the Metadata can tell the helper whether or not to render a control or it can make it read-only/disabled. Rather than re-invent the wheel here I just want to use what is already in place by changing the metadata within an action filter based on logic at run time. I do not want this logic within my view and I do not want to have to create custom helpers for every single html control if I do not have to..

What I was trying to do was create an action filter to handle evaluating logic rules in my business layer and then make changes to the metadata for a given model.property.

The problem is that my modifications to the metadata do not seem to be making it to the view. It almost seems like my changes to the metadata within the action filter are not by reference so therefore I am not modifying the same instance that is used for the view?

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
    var trans = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(e => e.PropertyName == "Transaction").FirstOrDefault();
    trans.DisplayName = "Show FOO!";
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the `ModelMetadata.Properties` values in a filter in fact you cannot change them at all.

The problem is inside the built in `DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider` (to be precise `AssociatedMetadataProvider`'s `GetMetadataForProperties` method) namelly the `ModelMetadata.Properties` gets regenerated from the attributes every time you iterate over it.

So the items inside the `ModelMetadata.Properties` collection are immutable.

You can check it with debugging:

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
     var properties = filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties
     var trans1 = properties.Where(e => e.PropertyName == "Transaction").First();
     trans1.DisplayName = "Show FOO!";
     var trans2 = properties.Where(e => e.PropertyName == "Transaction").First();
}
```

The `trans1` and `trans2` will be different instances (you can check their hashcode) so `trans2` displayname will be the original displayname not "Show FOO!".

So you need to Extend/Write the a new `MetadataProvider` to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out after some trial and error. What i ended up doing was creating a custom metadata provider which allows me to modify the properties as needed.

Answer (score 0):

you could check the user's role in the view and make adjustments that way.  The role is evaluated server side before rendering the html

```
@if(HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("MyRole")) {
   <input type='text' id='txtSomeInput' />
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying not to do. Not so much for the user role aspect but we have some other logic that determines if certain data will be available for edit this year versus last year. The previous developers have been putting if statements all over the place to handle this. Now when a new year rolls around the code has to be updated in 50 or so places so that the logic will consider the new year. From one year to the next our scholarship applications may ask for different information, the view and the model still needs to support view/edit application data from the previous year.

Comment: I see now... what about a partial view for each new year?  Your scholarship model stays the same, but you have a dictionary<year, scholarship>. Then for _partial2012, you pass the scholarship of dictionary[2012].  I am having trouble thinking of a way you do it with one view that has various fields enabled or removed each year without all the if statements.

Comment: I don't mind the if statements as long as they are not in the view. I want to centralize this logic for maintenance. This is why I wanted to manipulate the metadata so that the html helpers can just do what they already do and I do not have to change anything there. I am looking at a custom metadata provider to see if that makes any difference.